# PASTE from clipbord in android

Tags: android

I am developing application where user will copy data in WebView by long pressing on text and then pressing default copy button. Now I want to PASTE that text as soon as user touches EditText. I do have listener on edit text don't know how to past.
Need Help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6651222/1937802

Comment: @Varun  Karhadkar You can do like this:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/6201127/1332870

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ClipboardManager mClipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
mEditText.setText(mClipboard.getText());
```

But, I would strongly recommend you go through the **[official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html)**.

Comment: I cant find getSystemService() eclipse is showing error and quick fix is suggesting create new method getSystemService()

Comment: Are you in an Activity? or a Fragment?

Comment: In fragment.. Now I am using context.getSystemService(context.CLIPBORD_SERVICE) and its working..

Comment: Yes, because you need to have the context of the Activity to call getSystemService. Great that you figured that out by yourself! Cheers!

Comment: Deprecated since API level 11

Answer (score 0):

The paste action should be done with this:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ClipboardManager.html

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers.

Comment: Deprecated since API level 11

Answer (score 0):

Since the accepted answer contains deprecated code... :

```
private String getClipboardItem() {
    String              clipboardText    = "";
    ClipboardManager    clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

    // if the clipboard contain data ...
    if (clipboardManager != null  &&  clipboardManager.hasPrimaryClip()) {
        ClipData.Item item = clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0);

        // gets the clipboard as text.
        clipboardText = item.getText().toString();
    }

    return clipboardText;
}
```